# Having a hard time understanding Git and Github's place on my web server

Tags: php, git, github

I'm a long time web developer just starting to use Git and Github for my first project. I've setup my Github repository, added a README file, committed it and pushed it to my origin master. It now shows up in Github just fine. I'm assuming that I now want to either pull, fetch, or clone this to my live site. Development is done in a separate staging area of the same live server so I'm confident that changes I make and commit will be OK for the live site. I'm not part of a team and it's a small project so I'm mostly just interested keeping a backup of code and tracking the changes.

Am I on the right track? I've tried a number of articles but I don't think I'm quite grasping it.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much the git... I mean gist of it.

Comment: OK great, what do I use though, clone? fetch? pull? One needs a bare repository? Will they all put .git files on the live site? Dont I need one that basically just downloads the files and merges them?
Thanks for the quick reply though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might find this as a good resource: http://progit.org/book/

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's pretty much it. I would suggest that for a free private repo, you look at something like unfuddle instead. This will ensure that no one can see your code. You can do the same with github but it's not free.